# Do we want to participate in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discusión, winter-bash

Those of you who have been here a while may remember [Winter Bash](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash).  **Spanish Language & Usage** did not participate last year for the first time.

It's coming up again, 15 December 2014 through 4 January 2015, and you, the community, get to decide whether we participate. A decision must be made prior to 1 December.

For those of you who may be new, Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

[image]

Sites vote explicitly to participate, and if the idea is welcomed by site's users, it will be enabled in the aforementioned period. It's important to know that even if Winter Bash is enabled, users can explicitly opt out if they want to (there will be "I hate hats" option on their profile page which will revert the site to its familiar look for the user).

Please vote on one of the answers below to indicate your opinion on the matter.

Comment: If a decision had to be made before Dec. 1st, you didn't give us much time to vote, especially considering that the meta section doesn't get new question on a daily basis, so is visited less often than the main site.

Comment: @Diego: Yes, it would have been good to ask earlier. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ¡Claro que sí!

Quiero Winter Bash!

Answer (score 0):

## Obviamente que no.

Winter Bash sounds stupid.