# ¡Empieza el Winter Bash! / Let the Winter Bash start!

Tags: discusión, winter-bash

¿Habéis visto un nuevo icono en la parte superior de la barra de usuario? ¡Se trata del [Winter Bash 2016](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)!

Tal como se explicó por aquí otros años ([2014, por ejemplo](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1404/1674)), es un evento anual que Stack Exchange celebra por Navidad.

Este año va del 19 de diciembre hasta el 8 de enero.

Veamos la descripción dada en [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256/83):

> Desde ahora y hasta el final del día <s>3</s> 9 de enero de <s>2016</s> 2017, de nuevo podrás ganar y mostrar sombreros por hacer todo lo que ya llevas haciendo en los sitios de la red Stack Exchange. Al igual que en años anteriores, para este evento estamos desplegando una colección de sombreros completamente nuevos (por si te lo preguntas, esto es porque en el equipo de SE amamos nuestras comunidades y creemos que merecen lo mejor, no porque olvidamos dónde guardamos los sombreros cada año). Y esto significa que debemos estar tremendamente agradecidos a nuestro diseñador freelance, [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com), quien muy hábilmente se ha encargado de convertir vagos conceptos de sombreros locos en hermosuras digitales por tercer año consecutivo.
>
> Los sombreros, para quienes no lo sepan, son algo así como las medallas, pero **mejores** porque los puedes "vestir" en tu avatar, mostrándolos donde quiera que tu avatar aparezca, ¡en toda la red! (y gracias al acto de amor de [Brian Nickel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860000/brian-nickel), ¡este año esto incluye también la aplicación de iOS!). Los actos que otorgan sombreros son un poco diferentes de los que otorgan medallas; para saber qué tienes que hacer para obtener estos ornamentos, visita [el mini-sitio de Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com). Hay un total de 28 sombreros que puedes ganar en las próximas semanas… más otros de los que no te vamos a decir nada. ¿Cuántos sombreros secretos hay, te estarás preguntando? Eso lo tendrás que averiguar por ti mismo. No vamos a estropearte la sorpresa.

Nota: así como otros años se consultaba qué hacer y solamente se jugaba en los sitios que así lo decidían, este último año Stack Exchange ha hecho que por defecto se juegue. Los moderadores del sitio recibimos un email de los Community Managers comentándoslo y yo opté por no consultarlo por aquí, pues el bajo volumen de actividad me hizo pensar que muy raramente llegaríamos al consenso de *no* quererlo. Por tanto, todo aquel que prefiera no tenerlo simplemente debe seleccionar *I hate hats* en el desplegable.

---

So we are in [Winter Bash 2016](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)! This will run from December 19 up to January 8 this year.

Quoting [Flimzy's explanation on Winter Bash 2014](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1404/1674):

> For those of you who may be new, Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

If you want to cheat a little bit, you can [keep track of all the hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/209901).

Comment: Vale, veo ahora que en el blog de Stack Exchange han añadido una publicación dando comienzo al Winter Bash 2016: [It's Hat Season...Announcing Winter Bash 2016](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016)

Comment: Acabo de ganar uno que es como una media luna amarilla, pero me dice que es un sombrero secreto y no tengo ni idea de cómo lo he conseguido... :D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo no se lo digas a nadie, pero en [esta publicación](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/209901) puedes encontrar algunos motivos :P Te queda muy bien la media luna por cierto :)